# how can i importing my database by doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, linux, symfony

I set up a test server that is seminar that the production server, for application in symfony 3.
the first thing I did was to export the MySQL database, and there I have a file XXXXX.sql.
I have reached this stage but I don't know how to import my database by doctrine.
if you have the answer, please help me.
thank you for your feedback.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: Since doctrine is a data mapper ORM, it's up to you to map the classes you create to the database.  While you could use generators to make the entity classes, you lose out on most of the benefits of data mapper over activerecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly import your xx.slq file to your database. Then be sure your configuration settings in symfony application is connecting with your DB.After that you can generate your entities from existing database.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html